# Javascript and undefined values

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a value in an object is undefined:
I have the following code

```
for (i=0; i<extra.points.length; i++){
    console.log(extra.points[i].coord)
    if (!extra.points[i].coord === undefined){
        console.log("creating");
        //rest of code
    }

}
```

extra has the following values:

```
{
    points:[
       {name:'adp', coord:undefined}, 
       {name:'pdp', coord:{x:324, y:482}}
    ], 
    bicetrix:[]
}
```

But it won't enter the if at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Hmmm, comparing boolean to underfined using strict equals :) You need `extra.points[i].coord !== undefined`

Comment: Also, `var` your loop variables.

Comment: You can check with hasOwnProperty.
if (extra.points[i].hasOwnProperty('coord')) { //Create something }

Comment: Surely `null` is a better choice here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of operators matters. Not `!` is evaluated before `===`.

I guess you mean

```
if (extra.points[i].coord !== undefined){
        console.log("creating");
        //rest of code
}
```

What you have written means "if not(something) strictly equals to undefined". Not something is always boolean i.e. true or false. Which by all means can't be equal to undefined.

Answer (score 2):

`!undefined` is `true`, and `true === undefined` is always `false`.